# Regex to find hex value greater than a specific value

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am trying to find a regex that would match occurances greater than a particular value.
I am currently using this to match instances greater than 0. I want to get the match only if its greater than 5.which means 0x2, 0x1 and 0x4 wouldnt be matched below

`Error.*[1-9|A-F]`

```
Errors : 0x22
Errors : 0x2
Errors : 0x67
Errors : 0xA1
Errors : 0x5
Errors : 0x4
Errors : 0x0 Not matched 
Errors : 0x1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Regex really isn't the right tool. You'll want to extract `[1-9|A-F]+` and then parse + compare the actual value

Comment: I agree with @MathiasR.Jessen. Using a regex to find the hex values of interest is (probably) okay. And while it is possible to craft a regex to match only the acceptable values that's really the wrong tool for the job. Especially since complex Python regexes are notoriously inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the examples, if `0x2, 0x1 and 0x4` should not be matched but starting at `0x5` you might use:

```
\bErrors\s*:\s*0x(?:[5-9A-F]|[A-F0-9]{2,})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bErrors\s*:\s*`
- `0x` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `[5-9A-F]` Match either a digit 5-9 or char A-F
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-F0-9]{2,}` Match 2 or more occurrences of a char A-F or a digit 0-9
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\b`  A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QZu5ih/1)

Or with a negative lookahead, asserting not 0 - 4 directly to the right:

```
\bErrors\s*:\s*0x(?![0-4]\b)[A-F0-9]+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JcYBCZ/1)